# Excel VBA query fetches 0 for time values from Access database

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA query rightly fetches the data from Access to Excel. However, the values for all the Time related fields are coming as zero. What should I do?

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=D:\Fair\Macro Workings\Genie Trackers\Ac Genie.accdb;DefaultDir=D:\Fair\Macro Workings\Genie Trackers;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout" _
    ), Array("=5;PWD="";UID=admin;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT * FROM `D:\Fair\Macro Workings\Genie Trackers\Ac Genie.accdb`.DailyActivities DailyActivities" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (DailyActivities.`Accountant`='" & UName & "') AND (DailyActivities.`Due Date`<={ts '" & BDate & "'}) " _
    )

    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database2"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database2").Unlist
```

The dates are coming as numbers but when we format it, that is coming right. However, the time fields are showing zero
[Screen shot of the excel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL1M4.png)

[Screen shot of both database and excel result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuBGw.png)
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Screenshot shows *Due Date* rendering non-zero. Please show first few rows of database table.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Parfait. I was traveling and could not reply immediately. Have added the image now. Please check...